# How can I make a generic function that prints to any output stream?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a generic function, `print_if(start, stop, condition, out)`, that will print all of the elements that satisfy the unary predicate condition to the output stream `out`. I know the body of the function still needs work, but I can't come up with how to make the stream generic.

Here is what I have:

```
template <class Stream, typename Iterator, class UnaryPredicate>
void print_if(Iterator start, Iterator stop, UnaryPredicate condition, Stream out)
{
    auto itr;
    while (start != stop) {
        if (pred(*itr) == true)
            out << *itr << endl;
    }
}
```

When I tried to test it using `cout`, I get an error that it cannot be referenced, and is a deleted function. I've tried substituting class `Stream` for `typename T`, but I still haven't had any luck.

Comment: You never initialize `itr` and, assuming you didn't call the function vacuously, `start != stop` will always be true. I assume you meant something like `auto itr = start`, `while(itr != stop)`, and `itr = std::next(itr)` somewhere in the loop. You also name your `UnaryPredicate` `condition` in the function signature, but you invoke it in the body of the function as though it's name is `pred`.

Comment: IIRC, file streams cannot be copied, so you can't pass them as by-value arguments. If so, you'll need the last argument to be `Stream& out`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you guys sm :)

Comment: You know that eg `void foo(std::ostream&)` is already all needed for *almost* any output stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're asking about is because you're passing `std::cout` by value.
You can't copy the standard output stream.
The key fix is I've identified `out` as passed by reference (`Stream&`).

There were other errors (all marked).
Roughly 30 years ago I made the same error in my first outing with C++ - tried to pass the output stream by value. Thanks for the trip down memory lane.
These are pretty much rights of passage.
Don't be disheartened that out of 7 lines of code 5 of them had errors.
You had the right idea! Stick with it.

This code outputs the even numbers in a provided range:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class Stream, typename Iterator, class UnaryPredicate>
void print_if(Iterator start, Iterator stop, UnaryPredicate condition, Stream& out)
{
    auto itr{start}; //ERROR: Had no initialiser.
    while (itr != stop) {//ERROR: Should use iterator (was start!=end)
        if (condition(*itr) == true)//ERROR: pred doesn't exist.
            out << *itr << std::endl;
        ++itr;//ERROR:Increment  
    }
}
    
int main(){
    std::vector<int> nums{0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,27,64};
     print_if(nums.begin(),nums.end(),[](int v){return v%2==0;},std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
0
2
4
8
64
```

Comment: And if you change `Stream& out` to `std::ostream& out`, you can get rid of the `Stream` template parameter altogether: `template <typename Iterator, class UnaryPredicate> void print_if(Iterator start, Iterator stop, UnaryPredicate condition, std::ostream& out)`